# How to invalidate a JCR session based on user inactivity in AEM?

Tags: session, aem, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am designing a solution for the use case where I am logging into my website in AEM 6.3 and would like to logout the user from the website after a definite time of inactivity.

However, I did not find any such method in the javax.jcr.session API which allows the same. For reference, I am looking something similar to the `setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)` method of HttpSession.

Also, if it is not possible in JCR Sessions, is it a conscious choice of design? If yes, what is the reason for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the jcr Session, sling creates a new session for every request, and closes it when the request is done. There is no jcr Session associated with a user session as such.

Sling delegates the user session to the underlying servlet container Jetty; which, with default config never clears the sessionid cache on the server. But the login-token cookie is not set any expiration date and is cleared when the browser session is closed.